# UpperCasing CSV Columns by reading the header

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that reads the csv, splits it, uppercases only ONE or ALL columns (by index) and joins it again.

I want to be able to uppercase multiple columns but I have no idea how.

This is my code.

```
def specific_upper(line, c):
    split = line.split(",")
    split[c] = split[c].upper()
    split = ','.join(split)
    return split
```

EDIT: I wanted to do this only with python ( No spark, if possible )

EDIT2 : This is for NIFI, so its jython and not 100% python.

Comment: What attempt have you made to do multiple columns and what didn't work?

Comment: @martineau used several "c" arguments

Comment: João: Please [edit] and add your attempt to do multiple columns your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily with [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) from pandas. Default behaviour is your first row in the csv contains the columns names.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('<filename>')
df.columns = [x.upper() for x in df.columns]
```

This will upper case all your columns. You can add some conditions in order to upper case only the columns of your desire.

Comment: Im doing this for nifi, so it reads jython and not python.
Forgot to mention !